# How to change DOM element text continuously in .5 sec: want to create a custom text scroller like marquee

Tags: javascript, settimeout, marquee

I want to create a text scroller. It will work like a marquee (with direction towards left). For this I have used following logic:

1. Strip first char of string.
2. Append it to end of string.
3. Update DOM with updated string value (continue this process).

But no success. The DOM element is not getting update.

```
<p id="para" style="display: inline-block;">this is para 1</p><br />
<a onclick="scrolltext()">Scroll Text</a>

    var str = ' '+document.getElementById('para').innerHTML;
    var len = original_len = str.length;
    function scrolltext(){

            while(len>-1){
                 var char_start = str.charAt(0)
                 str = str.substr(1);
                 str = str+''+char_start;
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = str;                       
                     len--;
                     if(len == 0) 
                       len = original_len;
                 }, 500);

            }
    }
```